# Problem with delegate Syntax in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I built a Testbox to learn something about threading in windows form applications.
Silverlight and Java are providing the Dispatcher, which really helps when updating
GUI Elements.

Code Samples:
Declaration Class Delegate

```
public delegate void d_SingleString(string newText);
```

Create Thread

```
        _thread_active = true;
        Thread myThread = new Thread(delegate() { BackGroundThread(); });
        myThread.Start();
```

Thread Function

```
    private void BackGroundThread()
    {
        while (_thread_active)
        {
            MyCounter++;
            UpdateTestBox(MyCounter.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Delegating TextBox Updates

```
    public void UpdateTestBox(string newText)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new d_SingleString(UpdateTestBox), new object[] { newText });
            return;
        }
        tb_output.Text = newText;
    }
```

Is there a way to declare the Declaration of the Delate IN the BeginInvoke Method?!

something like

```
BeginInvoke(*DELEGATE DECLARATION HERE*, new object[] { newText });
```

Many thanks,
rAyt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In many cases like this, the simplest approach is to use a "captured variable" to pass state between the threads; this means you can keep the logic localised:

```
public void UpdateTestBox(string newText)
{
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
        tb_output.Text = newText;
    });        
}
```

The above is particularly useful if we *expect* it to be called on the worker thread (so little point checking `InvokeRequired`) - note that this is safe from either the UI or worker thread, and allows us to pass as much or as little state between the threads.

Comment: Love your eloboration Marc. Just learned a lot more than reading the MSDN for 10 Minutes :)

Comment: Very elegant solution; that should really be the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: @Spence - this has nothing to do with STA/MTA; at all.

Comment: Sorry Fredrik. Thats looks quite better ;)

Comment: No problem rAyt; while we are all rep junkies, we must also be humble and promote the better solution ;)

Comment: The fact that you have to invoke on the UI thread to perform an update has nothing to do with Winforms being an STA threaded library?

Comment: @Spence - correct. It has nothing to do with MTA/STA, and everything to do with "thread affinity", which is an orthogonal (although related) concept.

Answer (score 4):

For simple delegates like this you can use the `Action<T>` delegate ([link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)) from the framework.

```
public void UpdateTestBox(string newText)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(UpdateTestBox), new object[] { newText });
        return;
    }
    tb_output.Text = newText;
}
```

That way you do not need to maintain your own delegate declarations.