# C# Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, controls

I am running a thread and that thread grabs information and create labels and display it, here is my code

```
    private void RUN()
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Location = new Point(12, 10);
        l.Text = "Some Text";
        this.Controls.Add(l);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RUN));
        t.Start();
    }
```

The funny thing is that i had a previous application that has a panel and i used to add controls to it using threads without any issue, but this one won't let me do it.

Comment: You can modify UI elements only from UI thread.

Comment: Separate the business stuff (info grabbing) from the UI (creating Labels).

Comment: why create thread just to add UI element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating controls in a non-UI thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040770/creating-controls-in-a-non-ui-thread)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot update UI thread from another thread:

```
 private void RUN()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    Label l = new Label(); l.Location = new Point(12, 10);
                    l.Text = "Some Text";
                    this.Controls.Add(l);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Label l = new Label();
                l.Location = new Point(12, 10);
                l.Text = "Some Text";
                this.Controls.Add(l);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use BeginInvoke to access the UI thread safely from another thread:

```
    Label l = new Label();
    l.Location = new Point(12, 10);
    l.Text = "Some Text";
    this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        //perform on the UI thread
        this.Controls.Add(l);
    }));
```

Comment: Couldn't use it
Error 1: Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Answer (score 3):

#### Your are trying to add control to a parent control from a different thread , controls can be added to parent control only from the thread parent control was created!

use Invoke to access the UI thread safely from another thread:

```
    Label l = new Label();
    l.Location = new Point(12, 10);
    l.Text = "Some Text";
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        //perform on the UI thread
        this.Controls.Add(l);
    });
```