# Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I know there are like another 100 questions just like this, but i dont seem to manage fixing my code. I have a class that returns a Control and i want to add this control to an Tabpage from an TabControl. Im sure im doing something retarded and i dont have any experience working with threads.
If i try to modify this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750872/c-sharp-controls-created-on-one-thread-cannot-be-parented-to-a-control-on-a-diff) it still doesn't work. But if i dont modify it, it does add an Label to my tab.

```
private void RUN()
        {
            document = new TextDocument(inputFile);//fileName
            if (tabControl1.TabPages[0].InvokeRequired)
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages[0].BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.Label l = new System.Windows.Forms.Label(); l.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 10);
                    l.Text = "Some Text";
                    tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(l);

                });//but if i have something like tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(document.controls.content); i get an error
            }
        }
```

I also tried using background worker, failed as well. if i dont use another thread it works, but i need the rest of the interface to work while that control is created ( i read from an xls file and create an ViewList which i then add to tabpage).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is...

Here's a control that is created in a different thread, but added in the main UI thread:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread T = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(RUN));
        T.Start();
    }

    private void RUN()
    {
        // control created in a different thread:
        System.Windows.Forms.Label l = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        l.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 10);
        l.Text = "Some Text";

        // control added in the main UI thread:
        if (tabControl1.TabPages[0].InvokeRequired)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages[0].BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {        
                tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(l);
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I know this example works. but when i create my control in a different class and i try to add it to my tabpage i get the cross thread error.

Comment: document = new TextDocument(inputFile); this line creates a new ListView control

Comment: I'm not familiar with TextDocument()...how is that creating a ListView?  The example above has the control created in a different thread and is not having  an issue.  This would be no different than a a different class returning it.  Please give more details...

Comment: TextDocument() its a class i created

Comment: If i dont try to use a thread/background worker and i just create the listview and then add it to the tabpage, it works ok

Comment: But if i try to display a big xls file, its time consuming and i cant afford having my UI sitting idle. So i have to use another thread

Comment: tell if you want me to start over with the explanation, i know its the best explanation ever

Comment: You do the "work" in the thread and only use BeginInvoke() for the **small** portions of code that actually update the UI.  You don't invoke the entire process.

Comment: yes, i understand that. in the beginInvoke() part i only add the control, i create outside of the invoke part. my problem is the error i get

Comment: might it have something to do with the fact that i create the control in a different class?

Comment: No...if you pass the reference to the created control it shouldn't be a problem.  Can you give any more code to demonstrate this?

Comment: Never mind, i found my problem. In the class i was creating the new ListView i set the control.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize); It seems that if i dont use the autoresize property i dont get that error. way to lose a day.