# How To Scan Files and Show Details of Current Scanning Without Making The Application Non-Responsive?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am developing a desktop application for pdf file management using C#.

When I search any folder for *.pdf the application stops responding for some time, which is undesired behavior.

I am using `XmlWriter` to write data (i.e. file name,author name,subject). Also I have a label to show current scanning of file but it only show last file after complition of scanning.

Comment: Hi all I did it by using backgroundworker. But a problem persist, when i reading current scanning through label it gave me error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on". Any clue why it is showing that error Thanks Regards Gourav Goyal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Haedrian's answer, I'd say that you could use the `ProgressChanged` event of `BackGroundWorker` to handle updating your progress indicators.

More specifically, you could raise that event with `ReportProgress` method, passing the name of the file curently scanning, and in the `BackGroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event handler you could update the label you want to use to show the file under scanning

Comment: Hi all I did it by using backgroundworker. But a problem persist, when i reading current scanning through label it gave me error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on". Any clue why it is showing that error Thanks Regards Gourav Goyal

Comment: read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/906097/333223) or [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/142069/333223)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem.

Basically the thread which displays the application is the thread which is doing all the work. So any updates/responsivness of the GUI will have to wait until its finished.

The solution to this is to make it multithreaded. The simplest way is to use a Background Worker thread which will do the writing searching and whatever, and just leave the main thread free.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Answer (score 1):

If you can update your program, .NET 4.0 has new IO functions that return before finishing:

For example EnumerateFiles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to create an extra thread you can call

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

in the loop. This keeps application responding and updates the label.

Comment: This solution keeps popping up.  It's like 'Whack-A-Mole' :((